# How to change the Country value to a dropdown field

Tags: address

This is something that has been terrible since day one in SF.

I want to replace the Country text field to a dropdown (without going into VF).

I have seen several solutions in the [AppExchange](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/results?filter=1&keywords=country&sort=8&type=Apps) - but am interested to know if anyone has experience, with a simple to implement solution.

The idea is to have a 3rd field that holds "Region" which is a collection of countries.

Comment: When you say, "The idea is to have a 3rd field that holds "Region" which is a collection of countries.", do you mean that is your planned workaround? Or do you have a requirement for a picklist called Region in addition to a Country picklist? I'd like to understand so I can help answer whether state and country picklists beta would work for you.

Comment: The region will be a calculated field from the country, for reports purpose only.

Comment: Ah, cool. State and Country Picklists should be a great option for you, then.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This may not be 100% what you need, but might at least provide some improvement...

In **Spring'13**, Salesforce announced the '[State and Country Picklist Beta](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_state_country_picklists_overview.htm&language=en_US)'. It can be currently configured only via the Metadata API and only once the Salesforce Support team has enabled it for your org. Here is the [IdeaExchange](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrcnAAC) page for it, proof enough that at least sometimes our dreams come true! :-)

> State and country picklists allow users to select states and countries from predefined, standardized lists, instead of entering state and country data into text fields. State and country picklists allow for faster and easier data entry and help to ensure cleaner data that can be leveraged for other uses—in reports and dashboards, for example—with more dependable results. The state and country names in the picklists are based on ISO-3166 standard values, making them compatible with other applications as well.

**Video Demo:** http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=osSN804ILlI&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 1):

In spring 13 they have announced "`State and Country as picklist`". but They are in Beta version right now.

Comment: yea, had you noticed, Andrew already answered that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure how to solve your problem, but we use a free application called CountryComplete which works extremely well and I would greatly recommend.

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000001SqRFEA0

The company that produces it also has a more advanced application called "AddressTools"

Hope this helps.

Comment: As you are affiliated to this company, please state that in your answer, and also add in your profile. SFSE is NOT an add space.